# Running a chef client from a workstation

Tags: chef-infra

I have already setup a chef server on one of my ubuntu 12.04 OS. The second ubuntu machine has a chef client running which I use as a workstation to manage other nodes.

So lets decide the nomenclature as follows:
Chef Server : S
Workstation : W
Chef Nodes N1, N2 ...

I have bootstrapped the chef node N1 from the workstaion W using chef bootstrap as given here http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Client+Bootstrap+Fast+Start+Guide

After this I am trying to run the chef-client command on N1 from my workstation W.
I am using the following command:

```
knife ssh name:chefNode -x ubuntu -P password "sudo chef-client"
```

This throws me the following error:
    ERROR: Server returned error for http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:4000/search/node?=name:chefNode&sort=X_CHEF_id_CHEF_X%20asc&start=0 &rows=1000, retrying 5/5 in 58s
ERROR: internal server error

Any help or clue is appreciated. Please answer

Answer (score 2):

Check out you rabbitmq-server. See if it is properly configured or not.

To Configure run these

rabbitmqctl add_vhost /chef

rabbitmqctl add_user chef testing

rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /chef chef ".*" ".*" ".*"'

Check out

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Indexer

Use sudo if you are not a root user.

Plus add this line in your sever.rb file which should be in your /etc/chef folder

amqp_pass "testing"

Restart rabbitmq-server service and everything should be working

Comment: this is already done friend... But I think this is not the problem.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and my problem was solved by this. Just Check whether everything is running properly.
couchdb, rabbitmq , Chef-Solr, Chef expander chef-server

Comment: ok thanks... You give me hope.. I will try this as soon as I can spare sometime.. Thanks for your sincere efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

The "knife ssh" command uses the *search* functionality of chef.
The link about [Chef Indexer](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Indexer) that @Manak Wadhwa suggested, says:

> *The Chef Indexer is comprised of a RabbitMQ message queue, chef-expander, which pulls messages from the queue and formats them, and chef-solr, a thin wrapper around Solr.*

So you could also check if chef-solr and chef-expander are both working and running. Verify that all configuration files have the correct server IP/ports for each component from:
 
- [Chef Server](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Server) 
and
- [Chef Configuration Settings](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Configuration+Settings) (check *solr.rb* and *server.rb*) 
Try a simple search from your workstation, for example:
`knife search node "*:*"` or even `knife status` (knife status uses search) to get a list of all nodes. I would prefer knife status, as it will return a list of all nodes, whereas knife search will return all nodes as objects and it won't help a lot if you have many nodes. Anyway, if the result is a list of all the nodes you have, then search is working as it should. If this is the case, then the next thing I would try is to rebuild the index with: 
 `knife index rebuild -y` from the workstation or change the maxFieldLength in solrconfig.xml, as described in more detail below (2).

Two more links to check with troubleshooting of search is:
 1. [[chef] nodes not showing up in `knife status`](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2013-01/msg00415.html) where the people on the opscode list try the `knife index rebuild -y` command to rebuild the search index and check chef-solr related directory permissions.

 2. [CHEF-2346](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2346) where they talk about the maxFieldLength in solr for systems that produce a large amount of indexing data. Indexing data, as you probably already know, is data produced from ohai and all attributes, nodes, databags etc. The case I had was with all my windows systems, as with most of the other people. (The reason I'm also providing this link is because I can't estimate the amount of your indexing data.) LDAP for example could produce a large amount of data. Of course, if large amounts of data is your case, you can disable a few ohai plugins, if you don't need them. [(Check Disabling Ohai Plugins.)](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Disabling+Ohai+Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

A good practice when debugging problems with Chef Server & Co is, I found, looking in the logs of the server. For Chef Server 11 you simply do that with

```
$ sudo chef-server-ctl tail
```

or

```
$ sudo chef-server-ctl [<service name>] tail
```

For this specific problem I would do

```
$ sudo chef-server-ctl erchef tail
```

You can see the responses to requests and a short message about what fails under msg=[...]

Also, for debugging problems encountered when running knife, I would set

```
log_level                :debug
```

in knife.rb.